# AttributeError: module 'plotly.validators.layout.template.data' has no attribute 'IsosurfacesValidator'

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipython-notebook, plotly

Tenho um gráfico interativo em python. O código abaixo funciona no Azure Notebook, porém tive que migrar meu código para o JupyterLab e ele esta apresentando o seguinte erro:

> AttributeError: module 'plotly.validators.layout.template.data' has no
>   attribute 'IsosurfacesValidator'

Segue o código.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.offline as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
py.init_notebook_mode(connected=True)

trace = go.Bar(x = problema.index,
               y = problema)
data = [trace]

layout = go.Layout(title='Ranking de Problema',
                   yaxis={'title':'Quantidade'},
                   xaxis={'title': 'Problema'})


fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
py.iplot(fig)
```

Comment: Nunca usei o JyperLab. O que seria? Tem documentação dele?

Comment: Não sabia que a Azure tinha um serviço online disso. Já me cadastrei e estou usando. Que massa!

Comment: Oii, tem sim. Vou Segue o Link:
https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started/overview.html

O azure tem sim!!! e é excelente. É possível acessar de qualquer lugar o seu código. Amo isso nele!

Comment: Ahhh. É JupyterLab. Você escreveu Jyper, por isso não achei ele quando fui procurar no Google. É a versão mais nova do JupyterNotebook.

Comment: Então, a versão do Python é a mesma que você usava no Azure? Outra coisa, que linha dá esse erro?

Comment: hahaaha Corrigido! Obrigada!! ^^"

Comment: No canto superior direito do documento você pode ver a versão do Python para executar esse notebook.

Comment: Como eu faço para ver isso? Obs.: Comecei agora a aprender programar e estou começando com o python! ^^"

Comment: No JupyterLab eu acho que e a versão 3.7.2.

Comment: Entendi. Então, eu acredito que a biblioteca `ploty` não está instalada no seu projeto.
Pelo terminal ou CMD entre na pasta do seu projeto e digite: `pip install ploty`. 
Mas para isso é preciso ter o Python instalado no PC e também o `pip` para instalação de dependências.

Comment: Outra pergunta, seu código está inteiro na pergunta? Porquê eu rodei aqui e vi que `problema` não existe.

Comment: pelo CMD do Ananconda eu consigo fazer isso??

Comment: Sim, é pra conseguir.

Comment: fiz isso e deu o erro abaixo: 

Collecting ploty
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement ploty (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for ploty

Comment: Para quem nao conhece tem tb o [colab](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/welcome.ipynb#recent=true) tem até GPU free. Tentei rodar lá, mas o problema foi o `problema` que não está no código. :-)

Comment: Que ótimo Sidon!!

Comment: Muito obrigada, bom saber!!! =D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Descobri que estava apresentando esse erro por um motivo simples. Eu tinha que ter o Node.Js instalado na minha máquina para poder rodar este código no Anaconda / JupyterLab.

1º Passo: 
Baixei o Node.Js através do site: https://nodejs.org/en/ e instalei o mesmo.

2º Passo: 
Abri o CMD do JupyterLab e instalei a extensão do plotly, através do seguinte código:

```
jupyter labextension install @jupyterlab/plotly-extension
```

3° Passo: 
Executar o código que estava apresentando o erro abaixo novamente

> module 'plotly.validators.layout.template.data' has no attribute
>   'IsosurfacesValidator'